# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after changing nameserver for a domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, domain-name

Hello everyone I have a website which was hosted in digital ocean server and now i changed it to AWS. After changing the nameserver, when i access the domain i get error saying [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Is it normal to get this error after changing Nameserver? I did research on aftereffect of changing nameserver and came to know about domain propagation. So is this the error message i get when its in propagation state? Or problem could be something else?

I checked the domain in intodns.com and it shows record of new nameservers and IP ie AWS, but when i check with dig NS mydomain.com it show old IP and nameservers ie digital ocean.

Any idea what might be causing this? Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Make
sure your IP has been updated throughout the world DNS server.
You can check this by chang
for type this in NSLookup environment
4.2.2.4
If this is through please check your Local DNS or Cache setting

Comment: thanks for the response. NSlookup with 4.2.2.4 shows new IP, however without 4.2.2.4 it show old one. I have clear my local DNS cache. Does it takes time to change or something?

Comment: Hi. You should change your DNS server. Anyway if you wait for some hours it will be OK.